# Solaris 10 p2v conversion

Tags: conversion, solaris, p2v

I've picked up a system where the disk slices are odd and the ldmp2v prepare fails on disk sizes. I believe I have a mangled manifest file and I want to adjust it so it works.  Does anybody have a full description of this file please?  Most of it is obvious, but when looking at the prtvtoc and this file, some numbers dont make sense to me.

The vtoc lines look OK, but the disk top one and the 3 x UFS ones dont? From another document, I believe if I get the disk size right, I can fix this.  It would be nice resolve the disk layout so it looks like it has a proper slice #2 also, but really not that important.

What I'm after is what the 3 numbers relate to in the ufs lines and on the disk0 line, is this bytes, blocks ? I upped the number to 286698623 but in the prepare phase I still got an error indicating the disk was too small.

```
**disk 0 /dev/dsk/c0t0d0 0**
hostid 84f252a8
ip aa.bbb.cc.ddd
memory 4088
net 0 bge0 aa.bbb.cc.ddd 0:14:4f:f2:52:a8
nodename xxx.xxx
os_release 5.10
swap 0 /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s1 16586864
ufs 0 / /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0 3987422 327942 208320
ufs 1 /usr /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s2 20183432 12550242 12348408
ufs 2 /var /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3 241789040 127114564 124696674
vtoc 0 /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0 0 2 00 16586880 4111104 20697983
vtoc 0 /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s1 1 3 01 0 16586880 16586879
vtoc 0 /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s2 2 4 00 20697984 20494464 41192447
vtoc 0 /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3 3 7 00 41192448 245506176 286698623
```